# Correct way to configure Grails/hibernate for Postgres SERIAL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails

When using the Postgresql SERIAL data type (i.e. auto generation of id sequence), what is the best way to configure that in Grails / hibernate? Doing nothing is not an option, because it defaults to a global hibernate_sequence (does not suit what we are doing here). I've read in some places you can set in mapping for it to be something like `generator: 'identity'`, but I've also read you should avoid that because it has to do another query to retrieve the ID's generated value. That would make sense, although I had some idea in my mind that Postgres had some way to return the SERIAL ID to the program on INSERT without another query. (or maybe I imagined that). The other option I guess is I know Postgresql auto-creates a sequence for each SERIAL, so I could set `generator: 'sequence'`, figure out which sequence is being used and set `sequence: 'my_table_my_id'` or whatever. Presumably that would work, but it kind of seems ugly to delve into the postgres implementation of SERIAL rather than just rely on the automatic mechanism.